# @Binding init with class

Tags: swiftui

I'd like to init an @Binding in a struct with an @State from a class.

See comment in code, "// problem here". I've tried:

```
$junk = model.$junk
junk = model.$junk
junk = model.junk
```

This compiles ...

```
import SwiftUI

struct Junk_Test: View {
    @Binding var junk: String

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(junk)")
    }
}


class JunkModel {
    @State var junk = "xyz"
}


struct Junk_Test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Junk_Test(junk: JunkModel().$junk)
    }
}
```

This does not compile ...

```
import SwiftUI

struct Junk_Test: View {
    @Binding var junk: String

    init(model: JunkModel) {
        $junk = model.$junk  // problem here
    }


    var body: some View {
        Text("\(junk)")
    }
}


class JunkModel {
    @State var junk = "xyz"
}


struct Junk_Test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Junk_Test(model: JunkModel())
    }
}
```

I would think these would both compile. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`$junk` accesses the [projection property](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md#-identifiers) while 
`_junk` is the [synthesized storage property](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md#initialization-of-synthesized-storage-properties) you want to initialize.

Comment: I spoke too soon. That compiles however the following line gives a run-time error, "Thread 1: Fatal error: Accessing State<String> outside View.body":                         _junk = model.$junk  // problem here

Comment: You can do the assignment .onAppear or change the state variable to an @ObservedObject with the accompanying changes.

Comment: Thanks, I think the @ObservedObject is the right way to do this

Comment: Coming to think if it. Exchange @State with @Published, make it `class JunkModel: ObservableObject` and access the binding with $model.junk instead. I read it a little wrong, since @State usually only makes sense in a View in the first place. How arc (object destruction/retainment) works in conjunction with bindings I can't tell so I would recommend storing the ObservableObject somewhere.